# Object Disposed Exeption on "await httpClient.PostAsync" when posting images

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

Hi guys i get an ObjectDisposedException when adding the following code to my MultipartFormDataContent in Xamarin

```
JToken jobectImages = rootObject["Images"];

                foreach (var item in jobectImages)
                {
                    foreach (var internalitem in item)
                    {
                        foreach (var imageGroup in internalitem)
                        {
                            foreach (JObject image in imageGroup)
                            {
                                string sFileName = "";
                                string sFile2 = "";

                                try
                                {
                                    sFileName = image.GetValue("FileName").ToString();
                                    sFile2 = image.GetValue("FilePath").ToString();
                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                    sFileName = "";
                                    sFile2 = "";
                                }

                                if (sFile2 != "" && File.Exists(sFile2))
                                {
                                    StreamContent s = await Imagestream(sFile2);
                                    if (s != null)
                                    {
                                        multipartContent.Add(s, sFileName, sFileName);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Bellow is my image stream method

```
public async Task<StreamContent> Imagestream(String FilePath)
        {
            StreamContent streamContent2 = null;
            if (File.Exists(FilePath))
            {
                FileStream fs2 = File.OpenRead(FilePath);
                streamContent2 = new StreamContent(fs2);
                streamContent2.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            }
            return streamContent2;
        }
```

Getting the error on this line

```
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(GlobalVariables.url, multipartContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

i am adding one other image to the MultipartFormDataContent before this also using the Imagestream method above...any help would be great thanks

Comment: Exception handling is a pet peeve of mine and yours is terrrible. Fors starts you swallow exceptions, especialyl Fatal ones. Here are two articles on the mater that I link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET As I see 0 Dispose calls/using directives (wich is a mistake in itself), I have to asume some of the function code throws an exception and calls Dispose on something.

Comment: Yes I know it's not the best but that's why I'm on stack overflow..we all have to start somewhere...i have tried using directives aswell and still same issue. Xamarin also has a bunch of bugs which are not directly related to c# errors so that's why I'm asking

Comment: As I said, I do link those articles often. Wich means it is common. In this case it might even be related to your issues (rather then me just peeving). If you swallow exceptions, all you get is more and less understandable followup Exceptions. I asume that is one such case.

Comment: Where is httpclient created and did you put it in a using statement? If so, please make it a static field instead and don't dispose it. Also since you are in control of the debugger. Set a breakpoint at that line and inspect each field.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out it was my StreamContent() it was being disposed automatically before being assigned to the MultipartFormDataContent To fix this i used the following

```
 MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    streamContent.Position = 0;
                    streamContent.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    memoryStream.Position = 0;
                    StreamContent content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);
                    content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/octet-stream");


            multipartContent.Add(content, "signature", "signature.png");
```